# Why do I lack permissions to install jEdit in C:\Program Files (x86)\jEdit 4.5.0?

Tags: windows-7, windows, jedit

I am trying to install jEdit on my Windows 7 PC using the Java-based installer. However, I am getting this error that claims that I lack permissions to install jEdit within `C:\Program Files (x86)\jEdit 4.5.0`. I have verified that the folder does exist by pasting it into an address bar and going to it.

[image]

How come I can't install jEdit? I think I am the only user on my Windows 7 PC.

Comment: Maybe it's failing **because** the directory already exists?

Comment: Thank you, but I tried installing both with and without the directory `jEdit 4.5.0` made beforehand. Both times produced the above error.

Comment: Have you tried the [non-Java Windows installer package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedit/files/jedit/4.5.0/jedit4.5.0install.exe/download)?

Comment: Thank you, using the non-Java Windows installer worked. I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a run as administrator (or copy the file in using an administrator run Windows explorer).

Comment: I think I am logged in as an administrator though. I navigated to "User Accounts -> Manage Accounts" and saw that the label "Administrator" appeared below the user name of the user I logged in with. The only other user is "Guest."

Comment: @DavidFaux Starting in Windows Vista the adminstrator runs as reduced privlages, that is what the UAC dialog is for, elevating privileges. If you never got the UAC dialog then you need to manually elevate the process by doing Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, to write in Program Files and Program Files (x86) you need to be administrator.
Using the java installer java cannot ask to become administrator and complete the install.
You have to run the installer as an administrator or install jEdit somewhere else.